# What is the singular form of fennel?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

If I have one fennel bulb, what do I call it?  What is the singular form of fennel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Fennel*, like *rice* or *celery*, is a mass noun and normally occurs only in the singular.

Mass nouns aren't instantiated; they're abstract, or liquid, or granular, and don't occur in individualized pieces, like *beans* or *dogs* or *roses*, which are count nouns and have normal plurals.

So the plural of a mass noun often means different **kinds** of something, instead of different instances of it. Thus, *fennels, rices,* or *celeries* would mean different varieties of fennel, rice, or celery, if you needed to refer to them. Otherwise, mass nouns are used in the singular only.

You should be able to look this up in a good dictionary (not an American one). Look to see whether *bean* is marked as count and *rice* is marked as mass, so that you can tell that

- *a bowl of rice*
- *a bowl of beans*

are both correct, while

- **a bowl of rices*
- **a bowl of bean*

are both incorrect.